# When I redirect nginx https non-www -> www, do I need ssl on?

Tags: nginx, ssl, redirect, https

I'm using nginx with SSL, and I want to *always* redirect to www, regardless of whether the request is http or https. I just want to redirect to the respective protocol www version.

I have the port 80 server block working fine. Beneath my first server block I have...

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301  $scheme://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

and this works fine. But for my port 443 server block for https, I have all kinds of information inside regarding `ssl on` and different ciphers to use.

I really don't want to mess up anything up related to security by doing something stupid.. so my question is on this block for port 443...

```
server {
    listen      443;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301  $scheme://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

do I need anything else? do I need `ssl on` or any other security related things? If they visit non-www does that mean it transfers the request insecurely or something (even for a split second while its redirecting?)

Just want to make sure what I have is solid and secure. It seems to work but I want to double check.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes; pretty much whenever you have "listen 443" you also want "ssl on".

Note that you can have both in the same server definition though:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    listen      443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301  $scheme://www.example.com$request_uri;

    [... ssl config ...]
}
```